# Differential Equations question about the impulse function and some of its intuitive properties

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Alright, there is this three-part problem I am having some trouble with.

**Suppose we have a particle of mass *m*, initially at rest at the origin, that receives an impulse of *p* at time $t = 0$**.

(a) **Find the solution $x_\epsilon (t)$ of the problem $mx'' = pd_{0, \epsilon} (t); x(0) = x'(0) = 0$.**

This took me a bit to work out, but I solved it by treating $d_{0, \epsilon} (t)$ as the combination of a few unit-step functions. My reasoning is as follows: $$mx'' = p \frac{1}{\epsilon} [ u(t-a) - u(t-\epsilon)] = p \frac{1}{\epsilon} [ u(t) - u(t-\epsilon)]$$

Taking the Laplace transform of this yields the following $$ms^2 X(s) = p \frac{1}{\epsilon} [ \frac{1}{s} - \frac{e^{-\epsilon s}}{s} ] \rightarrow \frac{m\epsilon X(s)}{p} = \frac{1}{s^3} - \frac{e^{-\epsilon s}}{s^3}$$

Simplifying this equation and taking the inverse Laplace transform yields $$m x_\epsilon (t) = \frac{p(t^2 - u(t - \epsilon)(t - \epsilon)^2)}{2\epsilon}$$

Be aware that this part of the question IS NOT the source of my confusion, but rather required to understand the parts that *do* lend me some confusion.

(b) **Show that $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} x_\epsilon (t)$ agrees with the solution of the problem $mx'' = p\delta (t); x(0) = x'(0) = 0$**

I realized that $mx_\epsilon (t) = p\delta (t)$ can be rewritten as $mx_\epsilon (t) = p \lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} x_\epsilon (t)$, which thus implies that for $t \gt \epsilon$, then $mx_\epsilon (t) = \frac{p(2\epsilon t - \epsilon ^2)}{2\epsilon}$, and hence $mx_\epsilon (t) \rightarrow pt$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

**I looked to the back of the book and they offered the *same* reasoning. My question: HOW does this prove that $\lim_{\epsilon\to\infty} x_\epsilon (t)$ agrees with the solution? So what if $mx_\epsilon (t) \rightarrow pt$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?**

(c) **Show that $mv = p$ for $t \gt 0$ ($v =x'$)**.

For this part of the question, I had *no* idea. I don't even really know the intuition behind what they're asking. The back of the book just states "$mv = (mx)' = (pt)' = p$".

**How do I solve part (c) and what is the intuition behind solving it?**

Answer (score 0):

Part (b) is much like your companion question and has a similar answer. Saying that $x^{\prime}(0)=0$ doesn't make a whole lot of sense because there is a jump discontinuity of $x^{\prime}(t)$ of magnitude $\Delta x^{\prime}=\frac pm$ so if $x^{\prime}(0^-)=0$, then $x^{\prime}(0^+)=\frac pm$. As with the companion question, there is no jump discontinuity in $x(t)$, so $x(0^+)=x(0^-)=0$.

We can integrate the second differential equation for $t>0$ since $mx^{\prime\prime}(t)=0$, it follows that $x(t)=c_1+c_2t$ and comparing initial conditions, $x(0^+)=c_1=0$ and $x^{\prime}(0^+)=c_2=\frac pm$, so  $x(t)=\frac pmt$.

You had $x_{\epsilon}(t)=\frac pmt-\frac{p\epsilon}{2m}$, so the two solutions agree as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$

Part (c) is just differentiation. $x(t)=\frac pmt$, so $\frac d{dt}(mx)=m\frac d{dt}x=mx^{\prime}=mv=\frac d{dt}\left(\frac pmt\right)=\frac pm$.

Comment: How do you know that the jump at $t=0$ has a height of $\frac{p}{m}$?

Comment: And why $x^{\prime}$? How do we know that this has a jump discontinuity?

Comment: We can integrate to find $x^{\prime}(t)=x^{\prime}(-\infty)+\int_{-\infty}^tx^{\prime\prime}(\tau)d\tau=x^{\prime}(-\infty)+\int_{-\infty}^t\frac pm\delta(\tau)d\tau$. So when $t<0$, $x^{\prime}(t)=x^{\prime}(-\infty)$ and when $t>0$, $x^{\prime}(t)=x^{\prime}(-\infty)+\frac pm$. Just using $\delta(t)=0$ for $t\ne0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t)dt=1$ here.